# Reading and adding numbers from a text document in Python

Tags: python

I have a text document with a list of numbers, I need to have a function that reads all of them, and adds them together so then I can average them all out. I'm able to print the individual numbers and count the total numbers but not add the actual numbers together. Currently my code gives me "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

```
def CalcAverage():
    scoresFile = open("data.txt", "r")
    line = scoresFile.readline()
    scoreCounter = 1
    scoreTotal = 0
    while line != "":
        line = scoresFile.readline()
        total = int(line) + int(line)
        scoreCounter = int(scoreCounter) + 1
    print(total)   
    scoresFile.close()
```

Comment: "Currently my code gives me " Okay; so what is your **question**? Do you **understand** the error message? Did you [*try to figure out*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the cause? If so, *what did you learn* while doing so? What still confuses you about it?

Comment: (Hint: where the code says `line = scoresFile.readline()` inside the loop, do you see how that will affect the rest of the contents of the loop? Is it possible that `line == ''` for the rest of the loop contents? What would happen in that case?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is the error you're getting, replicated in the REPL:

```
>>> int("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Then the issue is that you're trying to cast an empty string into an `int`. This will naturally result in an error, and is a common one if you have empty lines in your file.

You sorta check against this:

```
while line != "":
```

But the issue with this is where you assign `line`: immediately after this check. While your first `line` value will be checked, it will be immediately replaced by a new `line = scoresFile.readline()`.

Thus, as you enter your while loop, `line` is the first line in your file. Then, it will assign the second line to `line`, dropping the first line's value. This will cause two different errors - one where you attempt in the following line to cast an empty string to an int, and one where you are ignoring the value of your first line. You need to alter how you do your check.

```
def calc_average():
    with open("data.txt", "r") as scores:
        counter = 0
        total = 0
        for line in scores.readlines():  # Returns the lines as a list
            total += int(line)
            counter += 1
    print(f"{total=} {counter=}")
```

Note these following good-hygeine practices in Python:

- Name your variables and functions using snake case.
- Use `with` to open a file. This calls `close` automatically, so you don't risk forgetting it.

Comment: The original approach would work if `line = scoresFile.readline()` happened at the *end* of the loop. However, this answer shows the standard and proper way to iterate over the file instead.